# In GWT, how to reference an external (obfuscated) CSS in another CSS file

Tags: css, gwt

I am using a GWT library that defines a CssResource with some class names in the associated css file, e.g. .someWidget {...}

Now in my code I would like to reference this 'external' and possibly obfuscated class name in my own css file. For instance to do:
.someWidget.animated {...}

Is there a way to achieve this?

(I know I could use @external .boxWidget if I would have control over the external library)

Comment: Is the external Library using a ClientBundle and CssResource Interfaces?

If so you can extend that interface, add own *.css files and the original ones.

Comment: It seems yours is the only way. If you add it as an answer with some detail, I would be happy to except it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the external Library using a ClientBundle and CssResource Interfaces? If so you can extend that interface, add own *.css files and the original ones.

```
@Source({"my.css","base.css"})
public CssResource css();
```

You also could completly disable css obfuscation. But thats not a good idea.